# How can I programatically calculate quantities based on length of material?

Tags: javascript, calculation

I'm trying to calculate the number of rolls of material that I could have if I cut a bigger size roll into multiple size smaller rolls.

For instance, if I have 1 25m roll I could cut that into 1 15m roll, 2 10m rolls and have 5 5m rolls. So I would want my quantities to look like:

- 1 25m
- 1 15m
- 2 10m
- 5 5m

Now, I could also have existing quantities of any of the other ones like 1 roll 25m, 1 roll 15m and 1 roll 5m. Then it would look like:

- 1 25m
- 2 15m
- 3 10m
- 9 5m

  ```
      for (let i = 0; i < this.sizes.length; i++) {
      const size = this.sizes[i];
      for (let j = 0; j < this.cart.items.length; j++) {
          const item = this.cart.items[j];
          if (item.sizeId === size.id) {
              size.quantity -= item.quantity;
          }
          size.amountOfMaterial = size.quantity * size.length;
      }
  }
  ```

I setup the first loop to get the correct quantity and amount of material based on what's already in their cart. I'm stuck on the next part.

Edit: The answer below eventually allowed me to come up with this:

```
calculateQuantities() {
    let quantities = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < this.sizes.length; i++) {
        const size = this.sizes[i];
        for (let j = 0; j < this.cart.items.length; j++) {
            const item = this.cart.items[j];
            if (item.sizeId === size.id) {
                size.quantity -= item.quantity;
            }
        }
        size.actualQuantity = size.quantity;

        let counter = 0;
        for (let j = 0; j < this.sizes.length; j++) {
            const otherSize = this.sizes[j];
            counter += Math.floor(otherSize.length * otherSize.quantity / size.length)
        }
        console.log(`${counter} ${size.length}m`);
        quantities[size.length] = counter;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < this.sizes.length; i++) {
        this.sizes[i].quantity = quantities[this.sizes[i].length];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I misunderstood the question, please let me know where I went wrong.
I am assuming the 25, 15, 10 and 5 are predefined. Is this correct? I didnt see this specified in your question.

```
// Defined lengths
const lengths = [25, 15, 10, 5];
// Some example cart corresponding to how many of each length customer has (this is from your example)
const cart = {25: 1, 15: 1, 5: 1}

for (let length of lengths) {
  //Check for each length in lengths array
  let counter = 0;
  for (let item in cart) {
    // Add the counter if there is enough in cart
    counter += Math.floor(item * cart[item] / length);
  }
  // I am console logging like you showed, but you can do whatever
  console.log(`${counter} ${length}m`)
}
```

Output:

```
1 25m
2 15m
3 10m
9 5m
```

Comment: Yes, they are predefined. Let me try out your answer and I'll get back to you. Looks similar to what I had.